# Как сгенерировать код P-XXXXXXXX, где X — числа [PHP]?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Коллеги, выручайте!

Нужно сгенерировать код, состоящий из одной буквы, затем дефиса и затем 8 цифр. (первая цифра не должна быть нулем)
Ну и соответственно перед занесением в БД я проверяю, есть ли такой код или нет.

Я с PHP не так сильно дружу, как с Javascript, на JavaScript я написал аж две функции (не могли бы вы их перевести в PHP (одну из них? ну или обе):

```
function generator(litera) {
  return `${litera.toUpperCase()}-${new Array(8)
    .fill()
    .map((el, i) => Math.max(i ? 0 : 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)))
    .join("")}`;
}
console.log(generator("i"));
```

litera --> эта буква до дефиса

```
function generator(litera) {
  const arr = [];
  arr.push(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9));
  for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  }
  return `${litera.toUpperCase()}-${arr.join("")}`;
}
```

Comment: в смысле return strtoupper($litera)."-".rand(10000000,99999999);?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На PHP можно так:

```
function generator($litera) {
  $litera = strtoupper($litera) . "-" . mt_rand(1, 9);
  for ($i = 1; $i < 8; $i++) {
    $litera .= mt_rand(0, 9);
  }
  return $litera;
}
```